# Google mod_pagespeed combining and url rewriting

Tags: mod-pagespeed

I fails to configure the module mod_pagespeed from google.
There is my site's .conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.a-very-new.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/a-very-new/web/"

    <Directory "/var/www/a-very-new/web/">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
ModPagespeed on
SetOutputFilter MOD_PAGESPEED_OUTPUT_FILTER
ModPagespeedFileCachePath            "/var/mod_pagespeed/cache/"
ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_css
ModPagespeedDomain http://dev.a-very-new.com/
```

my sites-available/mod_pagespeed config:

```
<Location /mod_pagespeed_statistics>
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from 127.0.0.1
 SetHandler mod_pagespeed_statistics
</Location>
<Location /mod_pagespeed_beacon>
 SetHandler mod_pagespeed_beacon
</Location>
```

The urls of my site are not changed :

```
<link href="/lib/mesLibs/cms/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/lib/mesLibs/cms/css/form.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/lib/mesLibs/cms/css/header.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/lib/mesLibs/cms/css/footer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and i got this kind of errors :

```
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/a-very-new/web/lib, referer http://dev.a-very-new.com/frontend/index/
```

An idea of what can be wrong ?

Comment: This doesn't look like a PageSpeed error, it looks like a generic configuration error with your path's. Try removing the PageSpeed logic and make sure that works first.

Comment: The paths configured with pagespeed or ...? Because my site works and firebug don't send me errors... I'll try to comment the five last lines in my first block code and I'll tell you if something changes.

Comment: The errors that I mentioned before were caused by my personal framework xD So the pagespeed problem don't come from these errors :( So you're right and my pagespeed problem comes from another things ... I will change my framework, but I still wait others answers :p

Comment: There's no problems anymore that comes from my framework but pagespeed doesn't combine my css files.

Comment: The strange thing is that in the cache directory there are the css. But Google doesn't do nothing with these css.